# Python del if in dictionary in one line

Tags: python, dictionary, del

Is there a one line way of doing the below?

```
myDict = {}
if 'key' in myDic:
    del myDic['key']
```

thanks

Comment: First thing to do with such questions: read the `dict` docs entirely.

Comment: @user683111: you should accept the answer, if it worked for you :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove a key from dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277432/how-to-remove-a-key-from-dictionary)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can write

```
myDict.pop(key, None)
```

Comment: It should only remove it if 'key' is in myDic (which is different than myDict)

Comment: @MichelKeijzers: Do you really think that is not a typo?

Comment: If not, it would be an empty dictionary and trying to remove an item would be useless.

Comment: yeah it was a impractical example, but it was meant for didactic purposes. It helped

Answer (score 4):

Besides the `pop` method one can always explictly call the `__delitem__` method - which does the same as `del`, but is done as expression rather than as an statement. Since it is an expression, it can be combined with the inline "if" (Python's version of the C ternary operator):

```
d = {1:2}

d.__delitem__(1) if 1 in d else None
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you call this a one liner:

```
>>> d={1:2}
>>> if 1 in d: del d[1]
... 
>>> d
{}
```

Comment: I call it not one line because it's two lines, just scrunched into one in a form not permitted by [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Two other reasons I'd never do it this way are (a) it's not as short and pretty; (b) it requires mentioning the dictionary name and the key twice each rather than once. The same arguments apply with `d[k] if k in d else v` versus `d.get(k, v)`.