# How does CPython determine whether a user supplied an optional argument?

Tags: python, python-internals

I started wondering how CPython can tell the difference between `None` as a default argument and `None` as a specified argument.

For example, `dict.pop()` will throw a `KeyError` if the key doesn't exist. `.pop()` also takes an argument for a default return value. In this example, we could set the default return to `None`, so: `some_dict.pop(some_key, None)`

If you were to define `pop` in Python, you'd probably have:

`def pop(some_key, default=None):`

In that case, it wouldn't make a difference whether you defined the `default` as `None` or just left it out, but Python can tell the difference. I did some digging in CPython and found the implementation of [`dict.pop()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L1866):

```
PyObject *
_PyDict_Pop(PyObject *dict, PyObject *key, PyObject *deflt)
{
    Py_hash_t hash;

    if (((PyDictObject *)dict)->ma_used == 0) {
        if (deflt) {
            Py_INCREF(deflt);
            return deflt;
        }
        _PyErr_SetKeyError(key);
        return NULL;
    }
    if (!PyUnicode_CheckExact(key) ||
        (hash = ((PyASCIIObject *) key)->hash) == -1) {
        hash = PyObject_Hash(key);
        if (hash == -1)
            return NULL;
    }
    return _PyDict_Pop_KnownHash(dict, key, hash, deflt);
}
```

I can understand roughly how that works. However, I can't seem to find `deflt` other than in that function definition (it's been suggested to me that CPython has a null pointer for None but I probably wouldn't recognise it), so I can't quite follow how CPython resolves the issue of whether or not a default was provided by the user. What is the execution path here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the second argument isn't passed, `deflt` is a null pointer rather than pointing to `None` or any other Python object. This is not something you can do with a function written in Python.

The function you're looking at isn't where the default value is defined. You're looking at an intermediate helper function. The default is specified in an [Argument Clinic](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/clinic.html) directive next to `dict_pop_impl`:

```
/*[clinic input]
dict.pop
    key: object
    default: object = NULL
    /
D.pop(k[,d]) -> v, remove specified key and return the corresponding value.
If key is not found, default is returned if given, otherwise KeyError is raised
[clinic start generated code]*/

static PyObject *
dict_pop_impl(PyDictObject *self, PyObject *key, PyObject *default_value)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=3abb47b89f24c21c input=eeebec7812190348]*/
{
    return _PyDict_Pop((PyObject*)self, key, default_value);
}
```

See the `default: object = NULL`. This comment is preprocessed to generate code that looks at `dict.pop`'s argument tuple and calls `dict_pop_impl`, and the generated code passes a null pointer for `default_value` if the argument tuple doesn't contain a value for that argument.

Comment: (Thinking in python logic) The null pointer trick could only be done with the last positional argument, right? Otherwise, I don't see how this works

Comment: @roganjosh: No, and I'm not sure how you got the idea that it would be restricted to the last positional argument.

Comment: You've edited since and now it makes more sense. To explain my logic for the previous comment `def x(a, b, c)` and you provided 2 positional arguments, it wouldn't be clear whether you provided a value for `b` at all

Comment: @roganjosh: Null default values can be used in Argument Clinic anywhere non-null default values could be used.

Comment: Now that you've shown the default is defined elsewhere, my point is moot and my thinking clearly incorrect. Thanks for the clarification :)