# Python: Preventing duplication of data when using dictionaries and lists

Tags: python

Hello Stack Overflow!

I am executing a simple command in a program that compiles a report of all the books contained in a library. The library contains a list of shelves, each shelves contains a dictionary of books. However, despite my best efforts, I am always duplicating all my books and placing them on every shelf, instead of the shelf I've instructed the program to place the book on.

I expect I have missed out on some kind of fundamental rule with object creation and organization.

I believe the culprits are the enshelf and unshelf methods in the book class.

Thank you so much for your time,
Jake

Code below:

```
class book():   

    shelf_number = None

    def __init__(self, title, author):
        super(book, self).__init__()
        self.title = title
        self.author = author

    def enshelf(self, shelf_number):
        self.shelf_number = shelf_number
        SPL.shelves[self.shelf_number].books[hash(self)] = self

    def unshelf(self):  
        del SPL.shelves[self.shelf_number].books[hash(self)]
        return self

    def get_title(self):
        return self.title

    def get_author(self):
        return self.author

class shelf():

    books = {}

    def __init__(self):
        super(shelf, self).__init__()

    def get_books(self):
        temp_list = []

        for k in self.books.keys():
            temp_list.append(self.books[k].get_title())
        return temp_list

class library():

    shelves = []

    def __init__(self, name):
        super(library, self).__init__()
        self.name = name

    def make_shelf(self):
        temp = shelf()
        self.shelves.append(temp)

    def remove_shelf(shelf_number):
        del shelves[shelf_number]

    def report_all_books(self):

        temp_list = []

        for x in range(0,len(self.shelves)):
            temp_list.append(self.shelves[x].get_books())

        print(temp_list)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#----------------------SEATTLE PUBLIC LIBARARY -----------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SPL = library("Seattle Public Library")                     

for x in range(0,3):
    SPL.make_shelf()

b1 = book("matterhorn","karl marlantes")
b2 = book("my life","bill clinton")
b3 = book("decision points","george bush")

b1.enshelf(0)
b2.enshelf(1)
b3.enshelf(2)

print(SPL.report_all_books())

b1.unshelf()
b2.unshelf()
b3.unshelf()
```

OUTPUT:

[['decision points', 'my life', 'matterhorn'], ['decision points', 'my life', 'matterhorn'], ['decision points', 'my life', 'matterhorn']]
None
[Finished in 0.1s]

..instead of [["decision points"],["my life"],["matterhorn"]]

Comment: Dictionary keys must be hashable and unqiue. List? Use ``set([....])` to get rid of duplicate. How big is ur data size? It's good to remove duplicate at once if it is small, but chunks when it is larger (at that point you want to use ``yield`` to feed back chunk of data instead,

Comment: Did you omit the `__init__` methods of your classes when you posted, or are the classes missing `__init__` methods?

Comment: Yes I ommited the __init__ methods, the code was really long.

Comment: It makes no sense to call `super()` in that way when you are not delegating any behavior to anything - you haven't given these classes a superclass from which to inherit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use [`dict.pop()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11277439/691859) instead of `del`.
2. Add `self.books = {}` to `shelf`'s `__init__`. Don't declare `books` outside of the `__init__`, because if you do so, all of the instances of that class are going to refer to the same thing. Instead, this makes each instance have its *own* dictionary, which is of course what you want since a book can't be in two shelves at once.
3. Do the same for `library` and its `shelves` and `book` and its `shelf_number`.
4. Pass a `library` instance as an argument to `enshelf` and `unshelf`. When you refer to `SPL` from within your objects' methods, Python finds that there is no local `SPL` defined, so it searches for one outside of the local scope; but if you were to try to assign something to `SPL` or do some other sort of mutative business, you would get an `UnboundLocalError`.
5. Bonuses:

   - `class book(object)`, `class shelf(object)`, and `class library(object)`. (Won't fix your problem, but you should do that anyway.)
   - You don't need to hash the keys before using them, they will be hashed (if they are hashable, but if you're hashing them, then they are).
   - There is no need to call `super()` unless you are inheriting from something, in which case you can delegate a method call to a parent or sibling using it - but you aren't doing that.
   - `get_books()` can be implemented as nothing more than `return [self.books[k].get_title() for k in self.books.iterkeys()]`
   - Likewise for `report_all_books()`: `return [shlf.get_books() for shlf in self.shelves]`. Note that I am not iterating over the indices, but rather over the elements themselves. Try `for c in "foobar": print(c)` in the interactive shell if you want to see for yourself.

Comment: Hey gents, I've updated the code and it includes everything now. I didn't communicate that I had the __init__ method already. @2rs2ts, thanks for the immediate response. I've got some nuggets now w/ your answer. I'm now a popper, not a deleter!

Comment: @JakeWay Ok, although my language will have to change, what you have to do is the same...

Comment: thanks for helping me cleanup my code! Hey I checked out your profile and github. When you're done with college be sure to apply at Digital Receiver Technology. (food for thought!) They look lame on their website but trust me, they do really coooool shit. ;)

Comment: @JakeWay If you're recruiting, feel free to email me about that sort of thing. Better to keep that sort of thing off of SO. :)

Comment: Ah gotcha, haha I'm no recruiter just know about them.

Comment: Thanks man, soon as I put everything in the inits.. it worked!