# Copying a dictionary into another dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm working on a game and one of the commands, one to pickup items, is not working. The code pretty much checks to see if the item is in the room and if it is then to copy that to the players inventory and then delete the item from the room. However no matter what I try it either does nothing or copies the keys inside to the dictionary.

Here's the code:

```
def pickup(self, item):
    conf = input('Do you want to pick up the ' + item.lower() + ': ')
    if conf.lower() == 'y' or 'yes':
        try:
            self.inventory.update(room[self.room_number]['items'][item])
            del room[self.room_number]['items'][item]
        except KeyError:
            print('You look everywhere but can\'t find a ' + item.lower())
    else:
        print('You consider it, but decide not to pick up the ' + item.lower())
```

When I print the inventory dictionary I get this

```
player.inventory
    {
     'type': 'weapon',
     'equippable': True, 
     'value': 0, 
     'desc': 'a wooden stick, could be useful', 
     'name': 'Wooden Stick', 
     'perks': {
         'defense': 0, 
         'health': 0, 
         'damage': 6, 
         'magic_damage': 0
     }
}
```

or

```
{}
```

What I want is this:

```
player.inventory
    {
    'wooden stick':{
        'type': 'weapon', 
        'equippable': True, 
        'value': 0, 
        'desc': 'a wooden stick, could be useful', 
        'name': 'Wooden Stick', 
        'perks': {
            'defense': 0, 
            'health': 0, 
            'damage': 6, 
            'magic_damage': 0
            }
        }
```

Does anybody know how I can get this result. Nothing I try seems to work and I have checked to see whether anyone has answered this but can't find anything on it.

Thanks :)

Comment: `if conf.lower() == 'y' or 'yes':` what do you think this does? Hint: `bool(str)` is `True`.

Comment: It's so that if the user enters YES or Yes I don't need all of the different ways of typing it. More for user friendliness that necessity.

Comment: This is not doing what you think it does. The condition above will be **always** evaluated to `True`. You should change it to: `if conf.lower() == 'y' or conf.lower() == 'yes'`.. Or use `in`.

Comment: You want `if conf.lower() in ('y' or 'yes')`, what you currently have evaluates if either `conf.lower() == 'y'` or if `'yes'` are `True`, but `'yes'` will always evaluate to `True`.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, didn't notice that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong function. In this line:

```
self.inventory.update(room[self.room_number]['items'][item])
```

`update` will essentially add all the keys and values from `room[self.room_number]['items'][item]` to `self.inventory`.

Instead, you want to assign the item dictionary as a value in the inventory dictionary, with a key for that item.

So you should do this:

```
self.inventory[item] = room[self.room_number]['items'][item]
```

Or better yet, as @MKesper points out, you should `pop` the key so that it's removed from the room's items dictionary when you put it into the inventory:

```
self.inventory[item] = room[self.room_number]['items'].pop(item, None)
```

This will attempt to get `item` out of the dictionary, and if it's not found `None` will be returned instead. If you remove `None` you'll instead have a `KeyError`, and depending on how confident you are in `item` being a valid key, a `KeyError` might be better to catch the unusual cases when incorrect keynames have appeared.

[Docs on `dict.pop`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop)

Comment: This seems to work. Thought I had tried that but had written self.inventory = room[self.room_number]['items'][item]. Should've worked that out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Additionally it's probably better to "pop" the key out of the dict: my_dict.pop("key", None) as written at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277432/how-to-remove-a-key-from-a-dictionary

Comment: Thanks, had read that but wasn't sure what it did. Reread it and it makes more sense now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use update method:

dict1.update(dict2)

Comment: Can't see anything. Maybe the links broken?

Comment: See seccond link, and click run