# Creating a Pandas dataframe from elements of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I'm trying to create a pandas dataframe from a dictionary. The dictionary is set up as

```
nvalues = {"y1": [1, 2, 3, 4], "y2": [5, 6, 7, 8], "y3": [a, b, c, d]}
```

I would like the dataframe to include only `"y1"` and "`y2"`. So far I can accomplish this using

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(nvalues)
df.drop("y3", axis=1, inplace=True)
```

I would like to know if it is possible to accomplish this without having `df.drop()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify `columns` in the `DataFrame` constructor:

```
pd.DataFrame(nvalues, columns=('y1', 'y2'))

   y1  y2
0   1   5
1   2   6
2   3   7
3   4   8
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `dictionary comprehension` to filter out unwanted `keys` like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k: v for k, v in nvalues.items() if k != 'y3'})
```

to get:

```
   y1  y2
0   1   5
1   2   6
2   3   7
3   4   8
```

There are of course quite a few ways to [remove one or more keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277432/how-to-remove-a-key-from-a-dictionary) from a `dictionary`.