# Delete JSON Objects Where Certain Keys Have Empty Values

Tags: python, json

I have a json as follows:

```
[{
        "Domain": "google.com",
        "A": ["172.217.22.46"],
        "AAAA": ["2a00:1450:4001:81e::200e"],
        "CAA": ["0 issue \"pki.goog\""],
        "MX": ["20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.", "30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.", "10 aspmx.l.google.com.", "40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.", "50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com."],
        "NS": ["ns1.google.com.", "ns3.google.com.", "ns2.google.com.", "ns4.google.com."],
        "SOA": ["ns1.google.com. dns-admin.google.com. 189483475 900 900 1800 60"],
        "TXT": ["\"docusign=05958488-4752-4ef2-95eb-aa7ba8a3bd0e\"", "\"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all\""],
        "Country": ["United States"],
        "Hostname": ["'fra15s16-in-f46.1e100.net'"],
        "SSL": ["Google Internet Authority G2"],
        "WHOIS": [8400],
        "TTL": ["24"]
    }, {
        "Domain": "",
        "NS": ["a.root-servers.net.", "h.root-servers.net.", "g.root-servers.net.", "i.root-servers.net.", "d.root-servers.net.", "k.root-servers.net.", "c.root-servers.net.", "l.root-servers.net.", "e.root-servers.net.", "m.root-servers.net.", "f.root-servers.net.", "j.root-servers.net.", "b.root-servers.net."],
        "SOA": ["a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2018031700 1800 900 604800 86400"],
        "A": [],
        "SSL": ["None"],
        "WHOIS": [0],
        "TTL": [null]
    }, {
        "Domain": "facebook.com",
        "A": ["157.240.20.35"],
        "AAAA": ["2a03:2880:f11c:8183:face:b00c:0:25de"],
        "MX": ["10 msgin.vvv.facebook.com."],
        "NS": ["a.ns.facebook.com.", "b.ns.facebook.com."],
        "SOA": ["a.ns.facebook.com. dns.facebook.com. 1521364737 14400 1800 604800 300"],
        "TXT": ["\"v=spf1 redirect=_spf.facebook.com\""],
        "Country": ["United States"],
        "Hostname": ["'edge-star-mini-shv-02-frt3.facebook.com'"],
        "SSL": ["DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA"],
        "WHOIS": [10227],
        "TTL": ["173"]
    }]
```

Please note the second element, the one that has `"Domain" : ""`, which I want to remove(there maybe multiple instances where `"Domain" : ""` is like that, this is only partial JSON) and return a valid json devoid of that whole object, so the output must look like:

```
[{
        "Domain": "google.com",
        "A": ["172.217.22.46"],
        "AAAA": ["2a00:1450:4001:81e::200e"],
        "CAA": ["0 issue \"pki.goog\""],
        "MX": ["20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.", "30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.", "10 aspmx.l.google.com.", "40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.", "50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com."],
        "NS": ["ns1.google.com.", "ns3.google.com.", "ns2.google.com.", "ns4.google.com."],
        "SOA": ["ns1.google.com. dns-admin.google.com. 189483475 900 900 1800 60"],
        "TXT": ["\"docusign=05958488-4752-4ef2-95eb-aa7ba8a3bd0e\"", "\"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all\""],
        "Country": ["United States"],
        "Hostname": ["'fra15s16-in-f46.1e100.net'"],
        "SSL": ["Google Internet Authority G2"],
        "WHOIS": [8400],
        "TTL": ["24"]
    }, {
        "Domain": "facebook.com",
        "A": ["157.240.20.35"],
        "AAAA": ["2a03:2880:f11c:8183:face:b00c:0:25de"],
        "MX": ["10 msgin.vvv.facebook.com."],
        "NS": ["a.ns.facebook.com.", "b.ns.facebook.com."],
        "SOA": ["a.ns.facebook.com. dns.facebook.com. 1521364737 14400 1800 604800 300"],
        "TXT": ["\"v=spf1 redirect=_spf.facebook.com\""],
        "Country": ["United States"],
        "Hostname": ["'edge-star-mini-shv-02-frt3.facebook.com'"],
        "SSL": ["DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA"],
        "WHOIS": [10227],
        "TTL": ["173"]
}]
```

Here is what I tried (the example is executable as is):

```
import json

if __name__ == "__main__":

    json_data = "[{\r\n\t\t\"Domain\": \"google.com\",\r\n\t\t\"A\": [\"172.217.22.46\"],\r\n\t\t\"AAAA\": [\"2a00:1450:4001:81e::200e\"],\r\n\t\t\"CAA\": [\"0 issue \\\"pki.goog\\\"\"],\r\n\t\t\"MX\": [\"20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.\", \"30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.\", \"10 aspmx.l.google.com.\", \"40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.\", \"50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.\"],\r\n\t\t\"NS\": [\"ns1.google.com.\", \"ns3.google.com.\", \"ns2.google.com.\", \"ns4.google.com.\"],\r\n\t\t\"SOA\": [\"ns1.google.com. dns-admin.google.com. 189483475 900 900 1800 60\"],\r\n\t\t\"TXT\": [\"\\\"docusign=05958488-4752-4ef2-95eb-aa7ba8a3bd0e\\\"\", \"\\\"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all\\\"\"],\r\n\t\t\"Country\": [\"United States\"],\r\n\t\t\"Hostname\": [\"'fra15s16-in-f46.1e100.net'\"],\r\n\t\t\"SSL\": [\"Google Internet Authority G2\"],\r\n\t\t\"WHOIS\": [8400],\r\n\t\t\"TTL\": [\"24\"]\r\n\t}, {\r\n\t\t\"Domain\": \"\",\r\n\t\t\"NS\": [\"a.root-servers.net.\", \"h.root-servers.net.\", \"g.root-servers.net.\", \"i.root-servers.net.\", \"d.root-servers.net.\", \"k.root-servers.net.\", \"c.root-servers.net.\", \"l.root-servers.net.\", \"e.root-servers.net.\", \"m.root-servers.net.\", \"f.root-servers.net.\", \"j.root-servers.net.\", \"b.root-servers.net.\"],\r\n\t\t\"SOA\": [\"a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2018031700 1800 900 604800 86400\"],\r\n\t\t\"A\": [],\r\n\t\t\"SSL\": [\"None\"],\r\n\t\t\"WHOIS\": [0],\r\n\t\t\"TTL\": [null]\r\n\t}, {\r\n\t\t\"Domain\": \"facebook.com\",\r\n\t\t\"A\": [\"157.240.20.35\"],\r\n\t\t\"AAAA\": [\"2a03:2880:f11c:8183:face:b00c:0:25de\"],\r\n\t\t\"MX\": [\"10 msgin.vvv.facebook.com.\"],\r\n\t\t\"NS\": [\"a.ns.facebook.com.\", \"b.ns.facebook.com.\"],\r\n\t\t\"SOA\": [\"a.ns.facebook.com. dns.facebook.com. 1521364737 14400 1800 604800 300\"],\r\n\t\t\"TXT\": [\"\\\"v=spf1 redirect=_spf.facebook.com\\\"\"],\r\n\t\t\"Country\": [\"United States\"],\r\n\t\t\"Hostname\": [\"'edge-star-mini-shv-02-frt3.facebook.com'\"],\r\n\t\t\"SSL\": [\"DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA\"],\r\n\t\t\"WHOIS\": [10227],\r\n\t\t\"TTL\": [\"173\"]\r\n\t}]"
    ds = json.loads(json_data)
    # cleaning empty entries
    for item in ds:
        try:
            if item["Domain"]:
                del item["Domain"]
        except KeyError:
            print("Key doesn't exist")
    print(ds)
```

However, I could not achieve my target. How to achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32509350/4180176 && https://stackoverflow.com/a/11277439/4180176

Comment: @JoshuaNixon went through them before posting, I think that would just remove the dict `"Domain" : ""` and not the whole obj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import json

if __name__ == "__main__":

    json_data = "[{\r\n\t\t\"Domain\": \"google.com\",\r\n\t\t\"A\": [\"172.217.22.46\"],\r\n\t\t\"AAAA\": [\"2a00:1450:4001:81e::200e\"],\r\n\t\t\"CAA\": [\"0 issue \\\"pki.goog\\\"\"],\r\n\t\t\"MX\": [\"20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.\", \"30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.\", \"10 aspmx.l.google.com.\", \"40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.\", \"50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.\"],\r\n\t\t\"NS\": [\"ns1.google.com.\", \"ns3.google.com.\", \"ns2.google.com.\", \"ns4.google.com.\"],\r\n\t\t\"SOA\": [\"ns1.google.com. dns-admin.google.com. 189483475 900 900 1800 60\"],\r\n\t\t\"TXT\": [\"\\\"docusign=05958488-4752-4ef2-95eb-aa7ba8a3bd0e\\\"\", \"\\\"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all\\\"\"],\r\n\t\t\"Country\": [\"United States\"],\r\n\t\t\"Hostname\": [\"'fra15s16-in-f46.1e100.net'\"],\r\n\t\t\"SSL\": [\"Google Internet Authority G2\"],\r\n\t\t\"WHOIS\": [8400],\r\n\t\t\"TTL\": [\"24\"]\r\n\t}, {\r\n\t\t\"Domain\": \"\",\r\n\t\t\"NS\": [\"a.root-servers.net.\", \"h.root-servers.net.\", \"g.root-servers.net.\", \"i.root-servers.net.\", \"d.root-servers.net.\", \"k.root-servers.net.\", \"c.root-servers.net.\", \"l.root-servers.net.\", \"e.root-servers.net.\", \"m.root-servers.net.\", \"f.root-servers.net.\", \"j.root-servers.net.\", \"b.root-servers.net.\"],\r\n\t\t\"SOA\": [\"a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2018031700 1800 900 604800 86400\"],\r\n\t\t\"A\": [],\r\n\t\t\"SSL\": [\"None\"],\r\n\t\t\"WHOIS\": [0],\r\n\t\t\"TTL\": [null]\r\n\t}, {\r\n\t\t\"Domain\": \"facebook.com\",\r\n\t\t\"A\": [\"157.240.20.35\"],\r\n\t\t\"AAAA\": [\"2a03:2880:f11c:8183:face:b00c:0:25de\"],\r\n\t\t\"MX\": [\"10 msgin.vvv.facebook.com.\"],\r\n\t\t\"NS\": [\"a.ns.facebook.com.\", \"b.ns.facebook.com.\"],\r\n\t\t\"SOA\": [\"a.ns.facebook.com. dns.facebook.com. 1521364737 14400 1800 604800 300\"],\r\n\t\t\"TXT\": [\"\\\"v=spf1 redirect=_spf.facebook.com\\\"\"],\r\n\t\t\"Country\": [\"United States\"],\r\n\t\t\"Hostname\": [\"'edge-star-mini-shv-02-frt3.facebook.com'\"],\r\n\t\t\"SSL\": [\"DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA\"],\r\n\t\t\"WHOIS\": [10227],\r\n\t\t\"TTL\": [\"173\"]\r\n\t}]"
    ds = json.loads(json_data)
    keep = []
    for item in ds:
        if item.get("Domain"):
            keep.append(item)
    print(json.dumps(keep))
```

This code builds a *new* list of the items to keep.

Comment: Being from a long Java background, this is most readable to me, selecting the same for answer

Answer (score 3):

```
[dom for dom in ds if dom.get('Domain')]
```

Uses a list comprehension to select all the dictionaries which have a non-falsey value for "Domain".

Answer (score 2):

The process of ***creating a new object*** by selectively choosing the required elements is better and less error prone than deleting elements and modifying the object.

Since you got `json` part covered, let me show you how to get the required `dict`. Its as simple as doing :

```
>>> [ele for ele in d if ele['Domain']]
```

Where `d` is the dictionary obtained from the input `json`.

#driver values :

```
IN : d = [{'Domain':'A', 'xyz':'abc'}, {'Domain':'', 'xyz':'bcd'},
          {'Domain':'C', 'xyz':'cde'}]

OUT : [{'Domain': 'A', 'xyz': 'abc'}, {'Domain': 'C', 'xyz': 'cde'}]
```

Comment: This could be written using truthyness of non-empty strings, which would arguably be more pythonic: `[ele for ele in d if ele['Domain']]`

Comment: @bgse : yeah. Wrote in the flow. WIll update. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are deleting keys from the objects and not the whole objects.

```
import json

if __name__ == "__main__":

    json_data = "[{\r\n\t\t\"Domain\": \"google.com\",\r\n\t\t\"A\": [\"172.217.22.46\"],\r\n\t\t\"AAAA\": [\"2a00:1450:4001:81e::200e\"],\r\n\t\t\"CAA\": [\"0 issue \\\"pki.goog\\\"\"],\r\n\t\t\"MX\": [\"20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.\", \"30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.\", \"10 aspmx.l.google.com.\", \"40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.\", \"50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.\"],\r\n\t\t\"NS\": [\"ns1.google.com.\", \"ns3.google.com.\", \"ns2.google.com.\", \"ns4.google.com.\"],\r\n\t\t\"SOA\": [\"ns1.google.com. dns-admin.google.com. 189483475 900 900 1800 60\"],\r\n\t\t\"TXT\": [\"\\\"docusign=05958488-4752-4ef2-95eb-aa7ba8a3bd0e\\\"\", \"\\\"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all\\\"\"],\r\n\t\t\"Country\": [\"United States\"],\r\n\t\t\"Hostname\": [\"'fra15s16-in-f46.1e100.net'\"],\r\n\t\t\"SSL\": [\"Google Internet Authority G2\"],\r\n\t\t\"WHOIS\": [8400],\r\n\t\t\"TTL\": [\"24\"]\r\n\t}, {\r\n\t\t\"Domain\": \"\",\r\n\t\t\"NS\": [\"a.root-servers.net.\", \"h.root-servers.net.\", \"g.root-servers.net.\", \"i.root-servers.net.\", \"d.root-servers.net.\", \"k.root-servers.net.\", \"c.root-servers.net.\", \"l.root-servers.net.\", \"e.root-servers.net.\", \"m.root-servers.net.\", \"f.root-servers.net.\", \"j.root-servers.net.\", \"b.root-servers.net.\"],\r\n\t\t\"SOA\": [\"a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2018031700 1800 900 604800 86400\"],\r\n\t\t\"A\": [],\r\n\t\t\"SSL\": [\"None\"],\r\n\t\t\"WHOIS\": [0],\r\n\t\t\"TTL\": [null]\r\n\t}, {\r\n\t\t\"Domain\": \"facebook.com\",\r\n\t\t\"A\": [\"157.240.20.35\"],\r\n\t\t\"AAAA\": [\"2a03:2880:f11c:8183:face:b00c:0:25de\"],\r\n\t\t\"MX\": [\"10 msgin.vvv.facebook.com.\"],\r\n\t\t\"NS\": [\"a.ns.facebook.com.\", \"b.ns.facebook.com.\"],\r\n\t\t\"SOA\": [\"a.ns.facebook.com. dns.facebook.com. 1521364737 14400 1800 604800 300\"],\r\n\t\t\"TXT\": [\"\\\"v=spf1 redirect=_spf.facebook.com\\\"\"],\r\n\t\t\"Country\": [\"United States\"],\r\n\t\t\"Hostname\": [\"'edge-star-mini-shv-02-frt3.facebook.com'\"],\r\n\t\t\"SSL\": [\"DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA\"],\r\n\t\t\"WHOIS\": [10227],\r\n\t\t\"TTL\": [\"173\"]\r\n\t}]"
    ds = [d 
          for d in json.loads(json_data)
          if d.get("Domain")
         ]
```

Comment: Your `if` might be more easily written: `if d.get("Domain")` since `get()` returns a Falsey value if the key is not found.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
for k in ds:
    if not ds[k]:
        ds.remove(k)
```

This way you're going to have `k` removed from `ds` if the value for `k` is either `0`, `None`, `False`, empty list or empty string and it would work for any given key.