# Throttling based on keys in python

Tags: python, throttling

I'm wondering if there is a way to throttle events in pure python.
For example, usually other tools have a way to look at a specific event, say:

```
{"id":111,"message":"hello","host":"example"}
```

and there might be another event that comes right after or within a time interval that looks like:

```
 {"id":112,"message":"hello","host":"example"}
```

Given these two events, you typically can look at 2 keys in the events, so for this example, the **message** key and the **host** key have the same values between the two events. Because these 2 events have the same **key and value**, you can treat them as one. This is how I would like to go about "throttling".

I'm wondering if there is a good way to do this in python, I'm thinking about using a database/redis but unsure what the best method is to approach this. For the events, the id is unique.

Thanks!

EDIT: I have actually already accomplished this is Logstash, but I was looking for a way to do it in pure python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this? I'm assuming these are dictionaries you're looking at (that's what they look like).

First, let `keys` be the set of keys you want to look for. Suppose `D` and `E` are the events you're looking at.

```
found = False
for k in keys:
    if D[k] == E[k]:
        keys2 = copy(keys)
        keys2.remove(k)
        for l in keys2:
            if D[l] == E[l]:
                found = True
                break
    if found: break
```

There's probably a better "Python way" to do this but it's been a while and I don't have time to look it up. At least this works on examples I've tried.

EDIT: Notice that if you only have those two keys you want to look for, you can discard both `keys` and the loop, and just test for them directly.

Comment: hmm interesting, and storing results over time? Say for example, 5 minutes? I'm guessing adding a new id for the matching events and then adding it to a dictionary and doing a lookup for any future events that might match?

Comment: If you don't care for the id's but want to filter by certain characteristics (which is what it sounds like), you can [remove the id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277432/how-to-remove-a-key-from-a-python-dictionary#11277439) and any other keys you don't want, convert the `dictionary` to a `tuple`, then add what remains to a set `S`. In that case, adding to the set automatically "throttles" repeated data. If you want to hold on to all the data, you can store unique items in a second list or set, adding to this second collection only when `S` doesn't contain what you want (`contains()`).