# Creating Dict from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm trying to create dictionary from DF however I'm not getting the desired output:

DataFrame:

```
A      B   C    D  
0.0   0.0 NaN  NaN 
0.0   0.0 NaN  NaN 
0.0   0.0 NaN  NaN 
0.0   0.0 NaN  NaN 
0.0   0.0 NaN  NaN 

data_dict1 = adsl.to_dict('list')
```

Current output: `{'A': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]}`

Desired output: `{'A': {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}}`

Difference is square braces instead of curly braces.

Comment: You realized that `{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}` is not a valid python representation, right? More precisely, it's equivalent to just `{0.0}`.

Comment: Yes sure, I'm trying to replicate an output from below code but my input is in csv which i'm converting to a dataframe. `dataset_dict2 = {
    name: set(choice(1000, 700, replace=False))
    for name in islice(letters, 6)`

Comment: @QuangHoang It's just representation for Yes/No (1/0) value.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an example `df`, [created from](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) a `dict`:

```
data = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

---

### You can do:

```
data_dict = df.to_dict('dict')
```

---

`data_dict` will be:

```
{'col_1': {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 0}, 'col_2': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd'}}
```

If you want to keep only `col_1`, you can, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11277439/8565438), *delete* `col_2` from `data_dict`:

```
data_dict.pop('col_2',None)
```

Your new `data_dict` will be:

```
{'col_1': {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current output is already a dictionary, mapping 'A' to [0.0,0.0,....].

**This is not a valid python expression:**

```
{'A':{0.0,0.0,....}}
```

But

```
data_dict = df.to_dict()
```

Should give you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment reply it seems you ARE looking for a unique set of values for each column. Try:

```
data_dict1 = adsl.to_dict('list') # which you already have, then...
data_dict1 = {key: set(vals) for key, vals in data_dict1.items()}
```

This will give you what you're asking for BUT it is bound to lose any sorting you have on the dataframe.

Comment: I get here an error `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

Comment: My bad, it was missing the `.items()`... try it now