# Ignore specific JSON keys when extracting data in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, key, extract

I'm extracting certain keys in several JSON files and then converting it to a CSV in Python. I'm able to define a key list when I run my code and get the information I need.

However, there are certain sub-keys that I want to ignore from the JSON file. For example, if we look at the following snippet:

### JSON Sample

```json
[
    {
        "callId": "abc123",
        "errorCode": 0,
        "apiVersion": 2,
        "statusCode": 200,
        "statusReason": "OK",
        "time": "2020-12-14T12:00:32.744Z",
        "registeredTimestamp": 1417731582000,
        "UID": "_guid_abc123==",
        "created": "2014-12-04T22:19:42.894Z",
        "createdTimestamp": 1417731582000,
        "data": {},
        "preferences": {},
        "emails": {
            "verified": [],
            "unverified": []
        },
        "identities": [
            {
                "provider": "facebook",
                "providerUID": "123",
                "allowsLogin": true,
                "isLoginIdentity": true,
                "isExpiredSession": true,
                "lastUpdated": "2014-12-04T22:26:37.002Z",
                "lastUpdatedTimestamp": 1417731997002,
                "oldestDataUpdated": "2014-12-04T22:26:37.002Z",
                "oldestDataUpdatedTimestamp": 1417731997002,
                "firstName": "John",
                "lastName": "Doe",
                "nickname": "John Doe",
                "profileURL": "https://www.facebook.com/John.Doe",
                "age": 50,
                "birthDay": 31,
                "birthMonth": 12,
                "birthYear": 1969,
                "city": "City, State",
                "education": [
                    {
                        "school": "High School Name",
                        "schoolType": "High School",
                        "degree": null,
                        "startYear": 0,
                        "fieldOfStudy": null,
                        "endYear": 0
                    }
                ],
                "educationLevel": "High School",
                "favorites": {
                    "music": [
                        {
                            "name": "Music 1",
                            "id": "123",
                            "category": "Musician/band"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Music 2",
                            "id": "123",
                            "category": "Musician/band"
                        }
                    ],
                    "movies": [
                        {
                            "name": "Movie 1",
                            "id": "123",
                            "category": "Movie"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Movie 2",
                            "id": "123",
                            "category": "Movie"
                        }
                    ],
                    "television": [
                        {
                            "name": "TV 1",
                            "id": "123",
                            "category": "Tv show"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "followersCount": 0,
                "gender": "m",
                "hometown": "City, State",
                "languages": "English",
                "likes": [
                    {
                        "name": "Like 1",
                        "id": "123",
                        "time": "2014-10-31T23:52:53.0000000Z",
                        "category": "TV",
                        "timestamp": "1414799573"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Like 2",
                        "id": "123",
                        "time": "2014-09-16T08:11:35.0000000Z",
                        "category": "Music",
                        "timestamp": "1410855095"
                    }
                ],
                "locale": "en_US",
                "name": "John Doe",
                "photoURL": "https://graph.facebook.com/123/picture?type=large",
                "timezone": "-8",
                "thumbnailURL": "https://graph.facebook.com/123/picture?type=square",
                "username": "john.doe",
                "verified": "true",
                "work": [
                    {
                        "companyID": null,
                        "isCurrent": null,
                        "endDate": null,
                        "company": "Company Name",
                        "industry": null,
                        "title": "Company Title",
                        "companySize": null,
                        "startDate": "2010-12-31T00:00:00"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "isActive": true,
        "isLockedOut": false,
        "isRegistered": true,
        "isVerified": false,
        "lastLogin": "2014-12-04T22:26:33.002Z",
        "lastLoginTimestamp": 1417731993000,
        "lastUpdated": "2014-12-04T22:19:42.769Z",
        "lastUpdatedTimestamp": 1417731582769,
        "loginProvider": "facebook",
        "loginIDs": {
            "emails": [],
            "unverifiedEmails": []
        },
        "rbaPolicy": {
            "riskPolicyLocked": false
        },
        "oldestDataUpdated": "2014-12-04T22:19:42.894Z",
        "oldestDataUpdatedTimestamp": 1417731582894,
        "registered": "2014-12-04T22:19:42.956Z",
        "regSource": "",
        "socialProviders": "facebook"
    }
]
```

I want to extract data from `created` and `identities` but ignore `identities.favorites` and `identities.likes` as well as their data underneath it.

This is what I have so far, below. I defined the JSON keys that I want to extract in the `key_list` variable:

### Current Code

```py
import json, pandas
from flatten_json import flatten
# Enter the path to the JSON and the filename without appending '.json'
file_path = r'C:\Path\To\file_name'
# Open and load the JSON file
json_list = json.load(open(file_path + '.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore'))
# Extract data from the defined key names
key_list = ['created', 'identities']
json_list = [{k:d[k] for k in key_list} for d in json_list]
# Flatten and convert to a data frame
json_list_flattened = (flatten(d, '.') for d in json_list)
df = pandas.DataFrame(json_list_flattened)
# Export to CSV in the same directory with the original file name
export_csv = df.to_csv (file_path + r'.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=None, header=True)
```

Similar to the `key_list`, I suspect that I would make an *ignore list* and factor that in the `json_list` for loop that I have? Something like:

```py
key_ignore = ['identities.favorites', 'identities.likes']`
```

Then utilize the [`dict.pop()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11277439/6579923) which looks like it will remove the unwanted sub-keys if it matches? Just not sure how to implement that correctly.

### Expected Output

As a result, the code should extract data from the defined keys in `key_list` and ignore the sub keys defined in `key_ignore`, which is `identities.favorites` and `identities.likes`. Then the rest of the code will continue to convert it into a CSV:

| created | identities.0.provider | identities.0.providerUID | identities... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014-12-04T19:23:05.191Z | site | cb8168b0cf734b70ad541f0132763761 | ... |

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: @MayankPorwal: I updated my question again, but I show which sub keys I want to ignore/skip in the JSON snippet above (`identities.favorites` and `identities.likes`) when I'm extracting the data.

Comment: please share json file which you are using

Comment: @Mannya; Updated the sample file. It's a large file, so I only included one record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the keys are always there, you can use

```
del d[0]['identities'][0]['likes']
del d[0]['identities'][0]['favorites']
```

or if you want to remove the columns from the dataframe after reading all the json data in you can use

```
df.drop(df.filter(regex='identities.0.favorites|identities.0.likes').columns, axis=1, inplace=True)
```