# How to remove or ignore an entry in a JSON file using python?

Tags: python, json

I am working on a code that extracts data from a JSON file here is the JSON file: [Google CDN](https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/cloud.json)

and here is a sample of JSON code:

```
{
  "syncToken": "1677578581095",
  "creationTime": "2023-02-28T02:03:01.095938",
  "prefixes": [{
    "ipv4Prefix": "34.80.0.0/15",
    "service": "Google Cloud",
    "scope": "asia-east1"
  }, {
    "ipv4Prefix": "34.137.0.0/16",
    "service": "Google Cloud",
    "scope": "asia-east1"
  }, {
    "ipv4Prefix": "35.185.128.0/19",
    "service": "Google Cloud",
    "scope": "asia-east1"
  }, {
    "ipv6Prefix": "2600:1900:40a0::/44",
    "service": "Google Cloud",
    "scope": "asia-south1"
  },
```

I know where the problem is but can not fix the issue with solutions on this website and getting another error every time.

This is my code

```
import json
f = open('cloud.json')
data = json.load(f)
array = []

for i in data['prefixes']:
    array = [i['prefix'] for i in data['ipv4Prefix']]
f_path = (r"ip.txt")
with open (f_path ,'w') as d:
       for lang in array:
        d.write("{}\n".format(lang))
f.close()
```

Basically I want to extract only ipv4 address but there are some ipv6 address randomly in block that causes this error so I get key error like this: KeyError: 'ipv4Prefix'

I know why I am getting this error so I tried deleting that whole entry with ipv6Prefix so I added this part to my code:

```
    if data[i]["prefixes"] == "ipv6Prefix":
        data.pop(i)
```

for this one I get TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' which is new to me, I also tried this as someone pointed out in another question but it didn't work.

```
del data[ipv6Prefix]
```

Now my final code is like this and getting this error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str which is understandable.

```
import json
f = open('cloud.json')
data = json.load(f)
array = []
for i in data['prefixes']:
    if [i]["prefixes"] == ['ipv6Prefix']:
        data.pop(i)
    array = [i['prefix'] for i in data['ipv4Prefix']]
f_path = (r"ip.txt")
with open (f_path ,'w') as d:
       for lang in array:
        d.write("{}\n".format(lang))
f.close()
```

So how can I delete entries with 'ipv6Prefix' or better to say, ignore them in my for loop?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65521978/ignore-specific-json-keys-when-extracting-data-in-python) question but answer does not fit my code at all.

what's the problem with my code?

I tried several methods like `del` and `dict.pop()` but still I get error.

Comment: `array = [i['prefix'] for i in data['ipv4Prefix']]` replaces `array` each time through the loop. You probably want to append to `array`, not reassign it.

Comment: There is no `data['ipv4Prefix']`. And it's not a list, so why do you want to loop through it? There's also no `prefix` key in any of the dictionaries, so what is `i['prefix']` supposed to be?

Comment: I don't think if append helps in this case but let me try it, and about `i['prefix']` you mentioned, if you open the link you'll see around 540 entries which is why I used this, it actually helps to call each entry in a time and then with `data['ipv4Prefix']` I can extract all ipv4 addresses, this is at least what I tried for another json file and worked perfectly, I can share the code if you like. @Barmar

Comment: @Barmar Check this [link](https://codeshare.io/PdEwNo), you can see I used same approach in both my codes but this only does not work because of random ipv6prefix objects in it

Comment: I checked the link, I don't see `prefix` anywhere. There's just `ipv4Prefix` and `ipv6Prefix`.

Comment: it's for another JSON file, code I shared in that link extracts data from AWS however in this code I shared on stack overflow I am trying to extract from Google JSON file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices: [Look Before You Leap or Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission](https://realpython.com/python-lbyl-vs-eafp/).  In short:

- **LBYL**: Do an `if` check to make sure `ipv4Prefix` exists
- **EAFP**: Assume that `ipv4Prefix` exists but catch the exception (a `KeyError` in this case)

Here is some code that demonstrates both approaches. It does not include writing out the results.

```
import json


def lbyl(data: dict):
    """Look before you leap"""
    ipv4s = []

    for prefix in data["prefixes"]:
        # Ensure that "ipv4Prefix" exists
        if "ipv4Prefix" in prefix:
            ipv4s.append(prefix["ipv4Prefix"])
    return ipv4s


def eafp(data: dict):
    """Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission"""
    ipv4s = []

    for prefix in data["prefixes"]:
        try:
            ipv4s.append(prefix["ipv4Prefix"])
        except KeyError:
            # This happens when "ipv4Prefix" is not in prefix
            pass

    return ipv4s


def get_data(path) -> dict:
    with open(path) as f:
        return json.load(f)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = get_data("cloud.json")
    print(lbyl(data))
    print(eafp(data))
```

Which style to use is subjective. Python has a reputation for preferring EAFP, but I prefer to use LYBL if errors are expected as part of normal operation. In your case you know that some objects will *not* have `ipv4Prefix`, so I contend that LBYL is more suitable here.

Comment: Both approaches are amazing didn't know LBYL is that handy

Comment: IMHO you should use LBYL when the difference is expected, while EAFP is for unexpected missing data. Python also has `dict.get()`, which can be a simple form of LBYL.

Answer (score 1):

> *So how can I delete entries with 'ipv6Prefix' or better to say, ignore them in my for loop?*

You can skip/ignore prefixes containing `ipv6Prefix` with `if...continue`:

```py
# import json
# with open('cloud.json') as f: data = json.load(f) ## safer than f=open...

with open ("ip.txt" ,'w') as d:
    for prefix_i in data['prefixes']:
        # if 'ipv6Prefix' not in prefix_i: d.write("{prefix_i}\n") ## OR
        if 'ipv6Prefix' in prefix_i: continue
        d.write("{}\n".format(prefix_i))
    ## list-comprehension INSTEAD OF for-loop:
    # d.write('\n'.join(str(p) for p in data['prefixes'] if 'ipv6Prefix' not in p))
```

You can write only prefixes containing `ipv4Prefix` with *`if 'ipv4Prefix' in...`*

```py
with open ("ip.txt" ,'w') as d:
    for prefix_i in data['prefixes']:
        if 'ipv4Prefix' in prefix_i: d.write("{}\n".format(prefix_i))
```

You can alter `data` itself to omit prefixes containing `ipv6Prefix` with [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension):

```py
data['prefixes'] = [p for p in data['prefixes'] if 'ipv6Prefix' not in p]
```

You can save a list of prefixes containing `ipv4Prefix` as JSON with `json.dump`:

```py
## to just save the list as a variable:
# ipv4Prefixes = [p for p in data['prefixes'] if 'ipv4Prefix' in p]

with open('ipv4Prefixes.json', w) as f:
    json.dump([p for p in data['prefixes'] if 'ipv4Prefix' in p], f)
```

---

---

> *getting this error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`*

That's probably due to the *`if [i]["prefixes"] == ['ipv6Prefix']:`* line; `[i]` is a **list** with just a single item [`i`, which is a dictionary], so *`[i]["prefixes"]`* just doesn't make any sense. You can use <kbd>`if 'ipv6Prefix' in i["prefixes"]`</kbd> instead, but there are more issues with what you're trying to accomplish in that block [I'll explain in the next section].

---

> ```py
> # for i in data['prefixes']...
>         data.pop(i)
> ```

The [`.pop`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/pop) method only takes an **integer** as input [which has to be the **index** of the item you want to remove from that list], but `i` is a copy of a *dictionary* inside `data['prefixes']`, so *`.pop(i)`* would raise an error if there's an attempt to execute it.

You could loop through [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)`(data['prefixes'])`<sup>(instead of just *`data['prefixes']`*)</sup> to keep track of the index associated `i`, but keep in mind that **looping through a list to `pop` multiple items [from that same list] is *NOT* advisable at all**. For example, if you pop the second item  from the list [index=1], then the indices of all items after it will decrease by one; so if you next need to pop what was *originally* the 5th item in the list, `enumerate` will tell you that its index is 4, but it actually became 3 after executing *`.pop(1)`*...

You *could* loop through the list in reverse as below (but isn't the list-comprehension approach I suggested before simpler?)

```py
for pi, p in enumerate(reversed(data['prefixes']), 1-len(data['prefixes'])):
    if 'ipv6Prefix' in p["prefixes"]: data['prefixes'].pop(pi)
```

<sup>Btw, instead of applying [`reversed`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/reversed), you can also use [slicing](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/list-slicing) like `data['prefixes'][::-1]`. I just thought using the function is better for readability because it makes it very obvious what it's doing.</sup>

---

> ```py
>     if data[i]["prefixes"] == "ipv6Prefix":
> ```
>
> *for this one I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'` which is new to me*

`i` is a dictionary (which is unhashable, as the error message said), and therefore cannot be used as a key the way *`....data[i]...`* is trying to.

---

> *so I get key error like this: `KeyError: 'ipv4Prefix'`*

probably from the `data['ipv4Prefix']` bit in the *`array = [i['prefix'] for i in data['ipv4Prefix']]`*, because `data` does not have a key `ipv4Prefix`; **some** `i`s in ***`for i in data['prefixes']`*** might, but there is **no point** in using <kbd>*`if 'ipv4Prefix' in i: del i`*</kbd> because `i` is a *copy* of an item in the list being looped though.

You can try using [`.remove`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/remove) like **`data['prefixes'].remove(i)`** [instead of *`del i`*], but I don't think that would be very efficient. List comprehension is definitely my preferred method in this case [and also probably considered the most "pythonic" approach here].

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried your solution and it worked perfectly.