# How do I remove a JSON element

Tags: python

My file:

```
{"704069756717629472": {"name": "Bob's Donuts", "value": 2}}
```

I want to remove this part:

```
"704069756717629472": {"name": "Bob's Donuts", "value": 2}
```

how do i do that?
this is my code:

```
if names in c[str(ctx.author.id)]["name"]:
    #remove the json thing
```

`c` is the loaded json file, `names` being the name of `c[str(ctx.author.id)]["name"]`, in this case, `"Bob's Donuts"`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277432/how-can-i-remove-a-key-from-a-python-dictionary

Comment: How are you reading the JSON file? Are you doing a simple file read? Or are you reading it with the json module?

Comment: oh ok ty @PaulRooney it works

Comment: @Edward I'm making Paul's suggestion official. Since you said it answered your question, you can accept the duplicate flag.