# Removing a dictionary key value having multiple value

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

My dictionary looks like this:

```
my_dict = {
   '0': ['1'].
   '3': ['2'].
   '1': ['0', '9', '3'].
   '4': ['1', '4'].
}
```

User will input a key and value. My function will delete that value from key, value pairs.

```
def deleteVal (my_dict, key_val, val):
   # write your function here
```

If any user removes a value from a key-value pair that has only 1 value, it will remove the entire key. For example: if user remove value `1` from `0`, the function will delete entire `0` key as it doesn't have any value left. 
How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried?  You did a great job describing the desired logic, the function writes itself

Comment: Subclass dict or write code

Comment: @Cireo Actually, I googled for half an hour. Didn't find anything suitable.

Comment: Not to be too harsh, but I see 18M results for 'python remove element from list', 4.5M results for 'python remove key from dictionary', and 102M results for 'python check if list is empty'.  30 minutes doesn't really cover no code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def deleteVal (my_dict, key_val, val):
    if len(my_dict.get(key_val, "1"))>1:
        try:
            my_dict[key_val].remove(val)
        except ValueError:
            pass 
    else:
        my_dict.pop(key_val, None)
```

Comment: val -> key_val in your `else`, and your len check is wrong, if you want to be full safe might also want to check key_val is present at all

Comment: @Cireo: *val -> key_val in your else* agreed; fixed. *your len check is wrong* don't agree; *if you want to be full safe might also want to check key_val is present at all* gotta leave something for the OP to do!

Comment: fair enough, there will be funny corner cases regardless of the implementation ;)

Comment: @CireoL See [How can I remove a key from a Python dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11277439/298607) No need to check for the key's existence...

Comment: Don't need a long comment chain, just saying you will throw KeyError before you get to `pop`

Comment: No you don't throw a `KeyError` if you use the default argument to `pop`; the default value is returned if the key is not present. Try it...

Comment: You *could* throw a KeyError at the `len` test but not at the `pop`

Comment: Yes, I'm just saying that `len(items[key])` will always be executed before `items.pop(key, None)`

Comment: @Cireo: Fixed using `.get`. Thanks