# How to remove a key from a dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a question about a simple quiz which is removing a specific key from a dictionary with function. Input must be taken from user. For example:

```
myDict = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4}

keyToRemove = ‘a’
```

would remove the first element from the dictionary and return the result.

I have developed such a code, but when I type 'a' it doesn't work. When I type only a it is removed. Could you help me to solve this question?

```
myDict = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4}
def key_Remover(Dict):
  x = input("Please enter dictionary key to remove: ")
  del Dict[x]
  return Dict


key_Remover(myDict)
print(myDict)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277432/how-can-i-remove-a-key-from-a-python-dictionary

Comment: the actual key is letter `a`, `'a'` is just how python displays strings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a key from a Python dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277432/how-can-i-remove-a-key-from-a-python-dictionary)

Comment: print repr(x) just before the del.  you may have some cleanup to do.

Comment: Quotes are valid string characters as well. When you enter 'a' it gets read as \'a\' which does not match the main key a. When you use input() the quotes are implied within code as that is how they are demarcated in Python strings

Answer (score 0):

`input` takes the user input as a string. If the user puts in `a` and hits enter, the input string is `'a'`. If the user puts in `'a'` and hits enter, the input string is `"'a'"`.

`'a'` exists in your dictionary, `"'a'"` does not.

Comment: Yes I realized that, but I didn't know how to do this like in the example. Because that is what the instructor wants.

Comment: @LucasMerten Are you sure your instructor wants the user to enter the key with quotes around it? That seems a strange requirement. Have you checked why they want that?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I pasted exact same question as an example.