# How can I remove null keys with values from JSON object in python?

Tags: python, django

I have a JSON object in which I want to remove the null key with the value that is my JSON. Please give me a solution how can I remove the null attribute with key and value from the object and can get without null keys data

UPDATE:

```
if request.method == 'POST': 
    all_products = request.data['products']
    
    db = CategoriesActiveORM.get_connection()
    keywords = db.table('categories'). \
        select('products', db.raw('count(*) as total')). \
        where_not_null('products'). \
        group_by('products'). \
        order_by('total', 'desc'). \
        limit(4). \
        get()

    total = keywords.sum('total')
    industries = {}
    for key in keywords:
        industries[key['products']] = round(int(key['total']) / total * 100, 2)
    
    print('industries', industries)
    
    industries = industries.pop("null", None)   

    print('industries', industries)
    
    industries.pop("null", None)
    rint('industries', industries)

    return JsonResponse(industries)
```

Print 1:

```
{
    "null": 87.37,
    " Product1": 4.95,
    " Product2": 4.44,
    " Product3": 3.24
}
```

Print 2:

```
None
```

Print 3:

```
{
    "null": 87.37,
    " Product1": 4.95,
    " Product2": 4.44,
    " Product3": 3.24
}
```

Comment: Just remove the key null. `dictionary.pop("null", None)`

Comment: Thanks @SembeiNorimaki for replying to me. That is not working giving null result after pop null

Comment: show us the code where you create your object how you apply the pop and print the value of your object after that

Comment: Sorry. I have updated my question. Thanks

Comment: Dear, @SembeiNorimaki I have updated my question. Know you can understand my problem. Sorry, i was creating confusion. Thanks

Comment: ok, I don't see in your code where are you applying the `industries.pop("null", None)` suggested as solution

Comment: let me define in code

Comment: Dear, @SembeiNorimaki I updated question with using ``pop`` methon

Comment: yes, but you should not assign the result of pop into industries. also, if you print industries before removing null you will still see the key. you should print after.

Comment: Yes. I have printed after then giving ``None`` not giving any result after pop ``null``

Comment: of course, because you are doing `industries = industries.pop("null", None)` instead of the suggested solution which is `industries.pop("null", None)`. You have an answer giving you the exact code you should execute.

Comment: Yes, I checked also with ``industries.pop("null", None)`` then not removing ``null`` key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to delete a key from the dict a similar question has been answered here:
[How can I remove a key from a Python dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277432/how-can-i-remove-a-key-from-a-python-dictionary)

You are assigning industries to the item you just popped from the dictionary.

**Solution A**

To fix this you must not assign the popped item to `industries`.

Just remove the `industries =` as follows:

**Before**

```
industries = industries.pop("null", None)
```

**After**

```
industries.pop("null", None)
```

This should give you the result you desire.

**Solution B**

If that didn't work try using `del` as follows:

```
del industries["null"]
```

**EDIT**

It seems like you forgot the quotations marks on the `None` key in the object, that seems to have solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks, bro for replying to me. but giving error ``KeyError: 'null'``. I am getting this JSON object from function and want to remove that.

Comment: I checked in the separate compiler working fine but in my code which is coming to the same result. but not working

Comment: Can you share the code for ```keywords```?

Comment: Okay let me define

Comment: Dear, @Liam I have updated my question. Know you can understand my problem. Sorry, I was creating confusion. Thanks

Comment: @Spiral, I updated the answer let me know if that works now?

Comment: Brother, @Liam I did check without assigning industries then not removing null giving the same results.

Comment: In online compiler is working fine but this response coming from above not working. I can't understand why Is not working

Comment: I updated my answer try solution B

Comment: giving error ``KeyError at  'null'`` at ``del industries["null"]``

Comment: That means that the key "null" does not exist so what do you see if you print industries?

Comment: Brother on print giving ``{None: 87.37, 'Product1': 4.95, 'Product2': 4.44, 'Product3': 3.24}``

Comment: Are you sure it's ```{None: 87.37, 'Product1': 4.95, 'Product2': 4.44, 'Product3': 3.24}``` and not ```{'None': 87.37, 'Product1': 4.95, 'Product2': 4.44, 'Product3': 3.24}```?

Comment: Amazing Dear Brother. That is working Fine. Thanks a lot