# How do I register a custom user type in Django 4.1?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

So, I am a beginner and I'm coding a django application that has a 3 user types in total but to make the code readable and understandable I'm just gonna assume we have 2 user types. One is a doctor and one is a patient.

**I've created this custom user so far:**

**`in models.py`**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_doc = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_patient = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()
```

**`manager.py`**

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password=None):

        if email is None:
            raise TypeError('Users must have an email address.')

        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user
    def create_patient(self, email, password):
        if password is None:
            raise TypeError('Must have a password')
        
        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_patient = True
        user.save()

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):

        if password is None:
            raise TypeError('Superusers must have a password.')

        user = self.create_user(email, password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save()

        return user
```

Patient Model is as follows:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=210)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=110)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=65)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

My form for Patient:

```
class PatientForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'address', 'phone', 'email', 'password']

        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First Name'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last Name'}),
            'address': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Address'}),
            'phone': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Phone Number'}),
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'}),
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password (Minimum Length: 8)'}),
        }
```

Current Views.py:

```
def RegPatient(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PatientForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            FName = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            LName = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            C_Address = form.cleaned_data['address']
            C_Phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            C_Email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            C_Password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            Reg = Patient(first_name= FName, last_name= LName, address= C_Address, phone= C_Phone, email= C_Email, password= C_Password)
            Reg.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/Login/')

        else:
            for field in form.errors:
                form[field].field.widget.attrs['class'] += ' is-invalid'
            return render(request, 'Home/RegPatient.html', {'form': form})
    
    else:
        form = PatientForm()
        return render(request, 'Home/RegPatient.html', {'form': form})
```

I have separate signups for patient and doctor and don't want a user type field in my form so I have all the detail fields in my form except user type.
How should my view look like so that it saves Patient with a user type is_patient? and am I missing something out? Cause I've tried to edit it so many times, tried getting help from Django Docs but I'm still stuck.

Comment: Share your forms and views code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, lets talk about the `Manager` and  `Models`. The `Manager` you are using is not really necessary, its possible to just set up the field on `User` object creation. As for the `Model` you can use [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) to have an extended `Patient` model based on your `User` model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_doctor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_patient = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Patient(User):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=210)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Patients"
```

Although, I would say the right approach to your problem is to use Django [authentication groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#groups), instead of adding fields to your `User` model.

As for the signup form, it should contain **confirmation and validation** of the password and the `username` field unless you are doing a login with email. To hold the information of `is_patient` field, use an `HiddenInput` (I couldn't replicate it with 'ModelForm' will need to dig further into that.):

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from django.forms import ValidationError

class PatientSignUpForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(
        required=True, 
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'username'}))

    first_name = forms.CharField(
        required=True, 
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'first name'}))

    last_name = forms.CharField(
        required=False, 
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'last name'}))

    email = forms.EmailField(
        required=True, 
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'email'}))

    address = forms.CharField(
        required=True, 
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'address'}))

    phone = forms.CharField(
        required=True, 
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'XXX-XXXXXXXXX'}))

    password = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    password_confirmation = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    is_patient = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)

    def clean(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        password_confirmation = self.cleaned_data['password_confirmation']

        if len(password) < 8 or len(password_confirmation) < 8:
            raise ValidationError("Passwords must have at least 8 characters")
        elif password != password_confirmation:
            raise ValidationError("Passwords must be equal")
        else:
            self.cleaned_data['password'] = make_password(self.cleaned_data['password_confirmation'])
            del self.cleaned_data['password_confirmation']
            return self.cleaned_data
```

Lastly, in `views.py` create an instance of `PatientSignUpForm` with an initial value for `is_patient` field.

```
from app import models, forms

def patient_signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.PatientSignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            models.Patient.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
            return redirect('')

    else:
        form = forms.PatientSignUpForm(initial={'is_patient': True})

    return render(request, 'patient_signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Wow, clearly explained! I'll try this approach right now. Just one more thing, lets say `User` has a field `first_name` and I later create another User type by inheriting User but I want the field `hospital_name` instead of `first_name` what do I do then?

Comment: Honestly, what you are asking doesn't make much sense, a `Hospital` would be another different entity than `Patient / Doctor`, so it would have a related FK. But it seems you are asking if there is a way to rename inherited fields and for that question I do not have an answer.

Comment: Oh I see, so what would be a good approach if I need to add another user type that does not have `first_name` and `last_name` field?

Comment: Btw, even after `del self.cleaned_data['password_confirmation']` Django still throwing an error about unexpected argument password_confirmation

Comment: In case of deeper customization make use of  `AbstractBaseUser`. Related to your problem `print(form.cleaned_data)` after validation to make sure `password_confirm` is not inside the dictonary.

Comment: @Nike Alright thanks, and yes I did that, `password_confirm` is still in the dictionary after `del`

Comment: That is awkward, it shouldn't. But, just [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11277439/7100120) it and create the object normally `models.Patient.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)`