# Python dictionary delete few fields which is inside nested dict

Tags: python

Here is the above dictionary
I need to remove fields like '**timestamp**' and field name '**updated_date**' inside attributes

How can i do it?

I'm using lot of loops thought that was not a good solution was checking for few code snippets on same to achieve this ?

I'm using  python version 2.7
dict:

```py
[{'name': 'mark', 'class': '9thgrade', 'timestamp': '2023-06-05 18:27:23.326', 'reg_no': 651,
          'attributes': '{"updated_date": "2023-06-05 18:27:22.543060", "hobbies": "" : " ", "sports": "cricket" : " ",'
                        ' "subjects":  {"": u"social", u"chemisty", u"cats": " "}, '
                        '"address":  {"cats": "UK,london"}}'},
         {'name': 'mark', 'class': '9thgrade', 'timestamp': '2023-06-05 18:35:32.386', 'reg_no': 661,
          'attributes': '{"updated_date": "2023-06-05 18:35:31.609323", "hobbies": "" : " ", "sports": "cricket" : " ", '
                        '"subjects":  {"science,maths"},'
                        ' "address":  {"texas,us"}'}]
```

I did try like below code but the return type is string :

```
for items2 in db_read:
    # result_new=items.pop('attributes')
    result_new = items2.get('attributes')
    print(type(result_new))
    print(result_new)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a key from a Python dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277432/how-can-i-remove-a-key-from-a-python-dictionary)

Comment: You _could_ try to use `eval()`, but your nested `attributes` dictionaries are malformed. Why?

Comment: How is `"hobbies": "" : " "` supposed to be interpreted?

Comment: The attributes value is a string. The string is not a representation of either JSON or a Python dictionary. The only way to remove 'updated_date' is with a string replacement / removal

Comment: Python 2,7 was replaced years ago and numerous changes were brought in; why are you still using it? Latest version is 3.11.3.